# Spring boot - json post request body as both POJO and string

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In a spring boot controller method, I can map the json post request body to a POJO e.g.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/abc")
public String handleABC(
        @RequestBody User user
) {
    //code here...
}
```

I can also retrieve the raw request body as a string:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/abc")
public String handleABC(
        @RequestBody String request
) {
    //code here...
}
```

My question is how can I map the request body to a POJO and also retrieve the raw request body as string (for logging purpose).

Thanks

Comment: Still relevant until this day. Have you found a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In general, SpringBoot will use Jackson as the serialization framework by default.

If there is no effect, you can Check your configuration, and inherit `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` rewrite `configureMessageConverters` serialization methods and specific behavior.

like this:

`I use FastJson as serialization framework, You can set up Jackson's configuration here instead of doing it like I did.`

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * custom MessageConverter
     * @param converters
     */
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        FastJsonHttpMessageConverter4 converter = new FastJsonHttpMessageConverter4();
        FastJsonConfig config = new FastJsonConfig();
        converter.setFastJsonConfig(config);
        converter.setDefaultCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        converters.add(converter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
@PostMapping(value = "/abc")
public String handleABC(
        @RequestBody String request
) {
    User user = objectMapper.readValue(request,User.class);       
    logger.log(request);
    //code here...
}
```